# MySQL, rename all the columns of all tables in a db

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

I have about 500+ tables in a db and need to rename all the columns of all tables.
The database engine is InnoDB.
Currently I'm executing a per table

```
ALTER TABLE RENAME db.table CHANGE oldID newID INT, CHANGE oldDESC newDESC VARCHAR(50);
```

And this is failing(errno: 150) at certain tables since they have foreign key constrains referencing to other tables.

Is there a smarter way of doing this and avoiding those dreaded errors?

Answer (score 1):

You can try disable foreign keys checks while do the update, then enable them again

EDIT: maybe [this](http://gauravsohoni.wordpress.com/2009/03/09/mysql-disable-foreign-key-checks-or-constraints/) can help

```
START TRANSACTION;  
SET foreign_key_checks = 0; -- off

.. do stuff here    

SET foreign_key_chekcs = 1; -- on.
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Make sure you really disabled them. But in case mysql will not let you do that because of any kind of reason, i guess you can try to drop them then put them back. this is more difficult. i don't know how can you make a backup of your foreign keys in order to restore them, but i guess there must be a solution.

Comment: And How do I know whether I have really disabled the foreign keys. I tried relocating the  
SET foreign_key_checks = 0; just before my renaming process, but even that is failing.

Comment: i don't know your setup. try with a simple test as in your example. disable checks than run an sql to alter the table. it's better to do this in phpmyadmin or mysql console so you will avoid any kind of dependencies

Comment: also, don't forget that when you make a backup/restore of your database, mysql will include disabling foreign keys checks before importing data, and set them at the end. and it works. or it should work. if not than you may have a problem with your installation :s

Comment: Ok! Is MyISAM anyway less stricter than InnoDB, see I'm working on a test framework so I can do some unusual stuff here to get the db working. Would it be possible to convert all tables to MyISAM and then do the rename. Would that be simpler?

Comment: I've got mysql5.5.8 running on WampServer2.1 and using that with a frontend HeidiSQL.